# Nested Tags Performance Improvements?

Tags: categories, performance, gwcode-categories

Is there a better (less server intensive therefore slow) way to retrieve entries based on a category setting i.e. this is what we currently use:-

```
 {exp:channel:categories channel="products" style="linear"}
    {if show_in_main_menu == "Yes"}
      {exp:gwcode_categories cat_id="{category_id}" incl_self="no" style="linear" disable="member_data|pagination|categories|category_fields"}
        [ENTRY DATA]
      {/exp:gwcode_categories}
    {/if}
 {/exp:channel:categories}
```

This currently takes about 3 seconds per iteration on our site (and we have to do something similar in 2 other locations) so we're getting ~10 second page load times which the client isn't happy about!

Answer (score 1):

Looping through categories and outputting entries within is an inherently "expensive" process. Someone will likely pipe in here with an answer that uses [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) to optimize this, but I'd suggest two options:

1. Use [CE Cache](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache) to cache this area of your template.
2. Use [NSM Categories](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories) to output your entries grouped by category.